# Link to 2022 survey broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, survey, survey-2022, insights

Congrats on the [2023 survey results](https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2023/) - interesting stuff in there!

I was curious how some of the results compare to previous years, and noticed that on https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey (googling something like "stack overflow past developer surveys" will take you there), the "View Results" link for the 2022 survey is broken.

It links to https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2022, but the correct URL is https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2022.

Comment: Fixed it! Thanks for reporting.